# Error while unfavoriting from favorites tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, favorites-tab

I encountered this error while trying remove a favorited question from the favorites tab on my profile:

[image: Error on favorites tab]

Steps to reproduce:

- Open own favorites tab.
- Click any star to unfavorite a question
- Error appears

If I click the star on the question page to remove the favorite, it works as expected. The error only appears on the profile page.

My Browser:

> Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: Confirmed with Firefox 22.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reason for error is the request URL which looks like this: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/undefined/vote/5` - the "undefined" cause 404 error. In this case browser isn't relevant.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd FWIW that it could easily have been caused by a script bug, which *might* be browser specific.

Comment: @p.s.w.g slight chance for that, modern browsers treat JavaScript pretty much the same and I'm sure the team is trying to use as much jQuery as possible which is cross browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, looks like some JS changes didn't account for the different markup hierarchy of the user profile.